# LinearLayout with nested RelativeLayout, order problem

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I've got a problem with 2 dynamically created Layouts, the outer one being a LinearLayout which contains a relativeLayout and a Button (just for testing, will me more buttons soon).

My Relative Layout is basically a 9x9 arrangement of Buttons for a sudoku game.

My Problem now is the following, i want the relativeLayout on top of the Button, not below it. Following code places it below:

```
MainLayout lay = new MainLayout(this); // MainLayout is derived from RelativeLayout
LinearLayout outerLay = new LinearLayout(this);
outerLay.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
outerLay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
Button but = new Button(this);

outerLay.addView(but);
outerLay.addView(lay);

setContentView(outerLay);
```

This works perfectly fine, but if I rearrange them it like this:

```
outerLay.addView(lay);
outerLay.addView(but);
```

the button doesn't even show up. Anyone has a clue on this? (Same happens to vertical btw.).

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your MainLayout lay is like :

```
setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Well there is no room on screen to display anything.

Your lay is too big. Check your layoutParams of it. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Wouldn't this be the case in order 1, too? Also i see enough unused space on the actual screen.

Comment: No because your button is certainly smaller. The unused space means nothing because your lay is not full of something to display.

Comment: Try : lay.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100, 100)); before your addViews.

Comment: Setting the relativeLayout eplicitly to  `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` still induces the same behaviour.

Comment: Thanks mthpvg, this seems to narrow the error down. The button is visible know, though i have serious problems with scaling. I will fix that, thanks for your help.